# 'NavigationExpandingExpressionVisitor' failed. This may indicate either a bug or a limitation in EF Core in .NET Core 3.1

Tags: .net, linq, asp.net-core, .net-core-3.1, versionupgrade

When I upgrade the project from .NET Core 2.2 to .NET Core 3.1, LINQ doesn't work.

These are my entity models:

```
public class Offer
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Desc { get; set; }
}

public class VendorOfferMembershipScheme
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Guid OfferId { get; set; }
}
```

When I try to get data using Linq with this code:

```
var data = (from offer in _dbContext.Offers
            join membershipscheme in _dbContext.VendorOfferMembershipSchemas on offer.Id equals membershipscheme.OfferId into ms
            from membershipscheme in ms.DefaultIfEmpty()
            select (prepareOfferData((membershipscheme == null ? null : membershipscheme), offer))).ToList();
```

I get an error:

> Processing of the LINQ expression 'DbSet\n    .GroupJoin(\n        outer: DbSet, \n        inner: offer => offer.Id, \n        outerKeySelector: membershipscheme => membershipscheme.OfferId, \n        innerKeySelector: (offer, ms) => new { \n            offer = offer, \n            ms = ms\n         })' by 'NavigationExpandingExpressionVisitor' failed. This may indicate either a bug or a limitation in EF Core. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101433 for more detailed information.

But it works fine in .NET Core 2.2.

Comment: Try a higher version. Why use versions that are deprecated?

Comment: That said, the reason is that `prepareOfferData` can't be translated into SQL, which caused EF 2 to auto-switch to client-side evaluation, which was a bad design decision.

Comment: Why is this there: `(membershipscheme == null ? null : membershipscheme)` ???

Comment: @NetMage, In my scenario sometime membershipscheme has a null value. So that.

Comment: So, in the expression `(membershipscheme == null ? null : membershipscheme)` if `membershipscheme` is not null, the value will be `membershipscheme` and if it is `null`, the value will be `null`, or the value of `membershipscheme`. So the expression is just a really wasteful complicated way of saying `membershipscheme`.

Answer (score 1):

You can manually switch to client side evaluation:

```
var data = (from offer in _dbContext.Offers
            join membershipscheme in _dbContext.VendorOfferMembershipSchemas on offer.Id equals membershipscheme.OfferId into ms
            from membershipscheme in ms.DefaultIfEmpty()
            select new { membershipscheme, offer })
            .AsEnumerable()
            .Select(mo => prepareOfferData(mo.membershipscheme, mo.offer))
            .ToList();
```

You can also use query syntax, but I don't find nested query syntax particularly readable:

```
var data = (from mo in
                (from offer in _dbContext.Offers
                 join membershipscheme in _dbContext.VendorOfferMembershipSchemas on offer.Id equals membershipscheme.OfferId into ms
                 from membershipscheme in ms.DefaultIfEmpty()
                 select new { membershipscheme, offer }).AsEnumerable()
            select prepareOfferData(mo.membershipscheme, mo.offer))
            .ToList();
```

Comment: It's working fine. But it takes more time to execute the query. and my project has so many queries like this. Is there any middleware method to configure?

Comment: @DilakshanAT It shouldn't take more time than .NET Core 2.2 - is it slower than 2.2?

Answer (score -1):

When I upgrade the project from .NET Core 2.2 to .NET Core 3.1, LINQ doesn't work.
Can you try this ;

```
var data = _dbContext.Offers
    .GroupJoin(
        _dbContext.VendorOfferMembershipSchemas,
        offer => offer.Id,
        membershipscheme => membershipscheme.OfferId,
        (offer, ms) => new { Offer = offer, MembershipSchemes = ms })
    .SelectMany(
        x => x.MembershipSchemes.DefaultIfEmpty(),
        (offer, membershipscheme) => prepareOfferData(membershipscheme, offer.Offer))
    .ToList();
```

Comment: This is just the same query but now in method syntax. Why would that solve the issue?